# Web3js Javascript Returned error: execution reverted

Tags: javascript, web3js

I have my own BSC node running for scraping data, sometimes there is a token that does not have the standard token info functions like name, symbol, totalSupply and decimals and my scraper will throw a error "Returned error: execution reverted". now I can't find a way to prevent from stopping the scraper if I get this error. I just want the scraper to ignore that token if it gets the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested. basically this is a double but I can not delete my question.

What I did to solve my problem is

```
await contract.methods.totalSupply().call().catch((err) => {
 return;
});
```

web3js can have a catch() to catch the errors.